# symmetric visitor pattern

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I'm using visitor pattern to define a set of operations on some classes.
Some operations are commutative, so I end up with duplication in the visitor pattern code.
Let's say I have classes A B C, and the operations: A*A, A*B, A*C, B*A, B*B, B*C, C*A, C*B, C*C.
A*A, B*B, C*C are unique.
A*B, B*A and friends will have code duplication
I could implement A*B, and make B*A call A*B but I will end up asking myself: in which file did I implement the operation between A and B again, in A or in B?  (there will be about 6 classes, so I will ask this question a lot. 15 pairs of possible operations)
There is a risk of someone in the future making an infinite loop of A*B calling B*A calling A*B when implementing a new operation.
It's unnatural to have a convention that decides which should be implemented A*B or B*A.
I could make a 3rd file with all the implemented functions which are called by either A*B and B*A, doesn't seem very object oriented.
How would you solve this issue?
Thanks
(I could list some code, but it's long and doesn't illustrate the point easily)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you should definitely refrain from implementing `A*B` as a call of `B*A`. In addition to a potential of creating an infinite chain of calls, that approach does not reflect  the symmetry of the operation in your code, because the code is not symmetric.

A better approach is to implement a "symmetric" operation in a helper class or as a top-level function, depending on what is supported in your language, and then make both `A*B` and `B*A` call that helper implementation.

Comment: there is a guideline that it's not exactly ok for class to use the attributes of other classes. I guess there isn't much of a choice

Comment: Scott Meyer has an excellent discussion on the topic in his More Effective C++ book (Item 31: Making functions virtual with respect to more than one object.) His example is making a collision function for a game where various objects may collide in space. His example is symmetric too (it does not matter if an asteroid hits a spaceship or a spaceship hits an asteroid, the explosion is the same). He starts with a visitor pattern, and gradually works out a C++ - specific solution that relies on RTTI.

Comment: @titus I am pretty sure that it is (I read that book in 1997, and the item was there).

Comment: I tried to implement with RTTI, I used typeid().name(), it was very slow, then I tried making a static function for each subclass that returns an int, this is one of the indexes in a function pointer matrix . It's still 3x slower than the visitor pattern. Here is the repository https://github.com/titusnicolae/comparison/blob/master/rtti.cpp

Comment: @titus That is very curious. Are your functions really fast, so the change of the dispatch mechanism causes a 3x slowdown?

Comment: I tried without any additional functionality, I just compared the dispatch mechanism. I need this dispatch mechanism for some math software, I'm looking to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: @titus Optimizing unfinished software (AKA "premature optimization*) is almost universally a non-productive way to spend your time. Profile your code under a realistic scenario, and see if the dispatch mechanism even pops up on your radar screen. Unless your math operations are very trivial, the change in dispatch mechanism would account for one to two percent of the overall time. Optimizing for 1..2% speed improvement are almost never worth the effort, because you'll find a bigger fish to fry in other parts of your code.

Comment: fair enough, I thought of optimizing it first because  it wouldn't be easy to modify this mechanism later. I'm making use of some very optimized math libraries in my code, there won't be much room for optimization later. It's true, I'm wasting time optimizing this. Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @titus It is not a certainty that changing your dispatch strategy later would be prohibitively expensive: the "beef" of your system is in these little code snippets to which you dispatch, not in the dispatch system itself. So if you decide that, for instance, using RTTI needs to be avoided, or that you need to use a custom indexing scheme of 1D array as 2D, all you need to do is changing the "harness" around your code snippets; the valuable part of your code will not need to change.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be use builder which will act as parameter Builder

```
new ParameterBuilder()
    .setFirst( "A" )
    .setSecond( "B" )
    .setThird( "C" )
    ...
    .build();
```

Then you will have only one method which takes `ParameterBuilder` as argument.

Comment: hmm, I could implement stuff as `Object* result = new MultiplyHelper().addOperand("A").addOperand("B").compute();`

Comment: I also have some non-commutative functions such A/B, using a symmetric construct as the above one for a non-symmetric operation is not ok. Better the other way around.

Comment: Parameter builder is just for taking parameters what you do with them is up to you. What your doing is also good. I suggested this solution to keep your methods intact and only change method signature.